# Recurrence in Math exercise

Tags: c++, recurrence

I am still trying to learn algorithms, I have a homework. I must make an output

```
Sum of : 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/6 - 1/8 + 1/10 + 1/12
Result : 0.975
```

But output of my program

```
Sum of : 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/6-1/8 + 1/10 + 1/12
Result : 0.975
```

I dont know how to make space `negative sign`, if i use cout there will show twice negative sign.

my program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int i ,sign, p, q, n;
    double x , S;
    S=0;
    cout << "Sum of :";
    for (i=1; i <= 6; i++)
    {
        if ( (i % 4 == 0) && ( i > 1 ) ) // to make condition where the number become negative
        {
            sign = -1;


        }
        if ( ( i % 4 != 0 ) && ( i > 1 ) )  // to make condition where the number become positive
        {
            sign = 1;
            cout << " + ";
        }
        if ( i == 1 ) // to prevent 1st number not show " + " symbol
        {
            sign =1;
        }

        p = sign*1;
        q = ( 2 * ( i - 1 ) ) + 2;
        cout << p << "/" << q;
        x = ( 1.0 * p / q );
        S = S + x;

    }

        cout << "\n" << S;
}
```

I realise that my program has too many operations which may be avoided, could u help me make it more effecient ?

Comment: If you have functioning code perhaps this is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: You could make the number always positive and then output the 'sign' of it independently. Then '-' would work just like '+'

Comment: Thanks you @EdChum for ur advice, sorry i am still dont know where to ask my program.

Answer (score 0):

So your

```
cout << p << "/" << q;
```

will always have that format if p is negative.
Instead (This workaround is intended to be simple)

```
if(p < 0) {
    cout << " - " << p*-1 << "/" << q;
} else {
    cout << p << "/" << q;
}
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to use recursion as you have indicated in the subject, then here is what you can also refer.

```
    static void recurse(int i, int limit){
            int sign = 0, p, q, n;
            double x, S;
            S =0;
            if (i == 1) // to prevent 1st number not show " + " symbol
            {
                    sign = 1;
                    cout << "Sum of : ";
            }
            else if (i< 1 || i> limit){
                    return ;
            }
            else {
                    sign = (i % 4 == 0) ? -1 : 1;
                    if (sign > 0){
                      cout << " + ";
                    }
                    else {
                      cout << " - ";
                    }
            }


            p = 1;
            q = ( 2 * ( i - 1 ) ) + 2;
            cout << p << "/" << q;
            x = ( 1.0 * p / q );
            S = S + x;

            recurse(i+1, limit);
    }
```

Call using:

```
int main ()
{
  recurse(1, 6);
  cout << "\n";
}
```